# why can't sh find executables bind mounted in docker container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, namespaces

Bind mount an executable into a docker container

```
docker run -it --net none -v /bin/dir:/bin/vdir busybox /bin/sh
```

Then attempt to execute the bound executable

```
# ls -al /bin/vdir
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        126584 Mar  2  2017 /bin/vdir
/ # /bin/vdir
/bin/sh: /bin/vdir: not found
```

Why can't `sh` find the executable?

Our only idea is that this is kernel related and something to do with the mount namespace?

```
uname -a
Linux eros 4.4.0-112-generic #135-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 19 11:48:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

On current Centos this works correctly.  Any ideas most appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be something to do with the container base image.  Running a container based on Ubuntu does not exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: Had a very similar problem, I dug more into it, it had to do with that executable already being installed in the base image in my case. Switched to a base image that didn't have said executable that I was mounting in and all worked as expected.